# how to prevent django, convert date to utc format

Tags: python, oracle, django-rest-framework

I get my date with time zone: "datetime": "2019-07-04T17: 53: 06-05: 00", when choosing save method, but in my bd oracle it is saved:
"2019-07-04T22: 53: 06".

I have already set USE_TZ: False.

```
serializer = self.serializer_class(data=json_data)
if serializer.is_valid():
pas_documento_guardado = serializer.save(usuario=usuario, tercero=tercero)
```

I hope it is saved in the database: "datetime": "2019-07-04T17: 53: 06",

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to define the proper `TIME_ZONE` in your Django `settings.py` file.

From [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE):

> Since Django was first released with the TIME_ZONE set to 'America/Chicago', the global setting (used if nothing is defined in your project’s settings.py) remains 'America/Chicago' for backwards compatibility. New project templates default to 'UTC'.

and also:

> When USE_TZ is False, this is the time zone in which Django will store all datetimes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the friend response, I attach my current settings, and timezone is with my time zone. LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-CO'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Bogota'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = False

Answer (score 0):

After continuing researching, I found the solution, the property 'TIME_ZONE' must be included in the properties of DATABASES in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'legacy': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'read_default_file': '....cnf',
    },
    'TIME_ZONE': 'America/Bogota',
},
'default' : {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'read_default_file': '....cnf',
    },
}
```

Thanks for the help.